# In ngx-datatable, while sorting multiple columns, can we make the sort sequence visible to the user?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable(https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable).
I have a requirement where users should see the sequence of sort when they sort multiple columns. multiple sorting is supported in ngx-datatable, but the sequence of sort is not displayed. can we display the number in the table header when multiple columns are sorted.